# Fn+Left/Right/Up/Down arrow keyboard shortcuts on MacBook Air m1

Tags: macbook-pro, keybindings

On my previous Mac (MacBook Pro 2012), <kbd>Fn</kbd> +  <kbd>←</kbd>  /  <kbd>→</kbd>  /  <kbd>↑</kbd>  /  <kbd>↓</kbd>  would by default be <kbd>Home</kbd> /<kbd>End</kbd> / <kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys, respectively.

On my MacBook Air M1 I can't get these shortcuts to work, despite [this Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236) listing them among default Mac keyboard shortcuts, and regardless of whether I assign the    / <kbd>Fn</kbd> key the    function or not.

Are these keyboard shortcuts no longer available, or have I inactivated them somehow?

I'm running macOS Ventura 13.2.1.

Comment: It’s not `Fn` but the `Ctrl` key you should be pressing

Comment: The default function of ```Ctrl``` + left/right arrows is to switch between spaces ("desktops"), so you are wrong here. This is copied straight from the article I linked above:
* Fn–Up Arrow: Page Up: Scroll up one page. 
* Fn–Down Arrow: Page Down: Scroll down one page.
* Fn–Left Arrow: Home: Scroll to the beginning of a document.
* Fn–Right Arrow: End: Scroll to the end of a document.

Comment: idk why they may not be working, but they *should* work. They have done on every Mac I've owned [well, maybe not back in System 6 days;) but currently on everything from an El Cap Mac Pro to a new M1 iMac, with settings at defaults. Do you have any 3rd party key mods at all? Karabiner, Ukelele etc, which could interfere?